# Filter products by date range in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to search products in WooCommerce by a date range, exactly per month. I set 2 custom fields for my products created with ACF (*acf-season_from* and *acf-season_to*). 
I tried using the *pre_get_posts* filter but does not work properly. Here my code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_shop() ) { return; }

    $current_m = date('m');
    $month = $_GET['m'];

    $year = date("Y");
    if( $current_m > $month)
        $year = date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));

    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        array(
              'key' => 'acf-season_from',
              'value' => date( "d/m/Y", mktime( 0,0,0,date($month),date('01'),date($year))),
              'compare' => '>=',
              'type' => 'DATE'

        ),
        array(
              'key' => 'acf-season_to',
              'value' => date( "d/m/Y", mktime(0,0,0,date($month),date("t"),date($year))),
              'compare' => '<=',
              'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    ) );

    return $query;} );
```

How can I apply the filter properly to the products loop, so only the products of selected month will be shown?

Thanks